# object detection using matlab computer vision toolbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

while developing simple algorithm for object detection in a scene with matlab tool box 
here is the code I wrote

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkV6v.jpg

then I found these errors 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xSXX.jpg

please can anybody help

Comment: Could you give your code and errors as text rather than as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `detectSURFFeatures()` takes a 2-D (grayscale) image as input. Your first image, `box_image`, is a color image. Convert it to grayscale by using the command `rgb2gray()` and use to detect SURF features.